# I need to break a string at 30 characters, and insert a - and newline

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to insert a BR tag at the 30th position of a string if it is longer then 30.
Also, if the 29th position is not a space i.e. " " then I need to insert a - character and THEN insert a BR tag.

I am having issues with getting this to work, specifically detecting the space character.

I tried the wbr character and others but none are cross browser so I'm just inserting a BR tag so the text wraps around at the 30th position and inserting a dash.

Comment: i didn't want to bias the responses with my hacks!

Comment: Your algorithm for hyphenating is flawed. You need to account for the possibility for the 30th char to be different than a letter - for example, if your string contains at position 29 and 30 something like  " -" or " (".

Answer (score 2):

```
public static string FixUp(string s)
{
    if (s.Length <= 30)
        return s;
    if (s[29] != ' ')
        return s.Insert(30, "-<br />");
    return s.Insert(30, "<br />");
}
```

However I assume you want to keep splitting till you have the whole string broken into 30 charter lines.

Further more your logic for hyphenation should allow or a space at the 29th or 30th character, as well as hyphens (really any sort of punctuation but I skip that here)

```
public static string FixUp2(string s)
{
    string result = "";     
    while (s.Length > 30)
    {    
        if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(s[29]) || Char.IsWhiteSpace(s[30]) ||
            s[29] == '-' || s[30] == '-')
        {
            result += s.Substring(0, 30)+"<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            result += s.Substring(0, 30)+"-<br />";
        }
        s = s.Substring(30);
    }
    result += s;
    return result;
}
```

This could be done faster but I believe you need to understand what is going on with simpler code first.

Comment: I'm with you on the "simpler code first" thing, but you'd definitely want to use a StringBuilder in production.

Comment: Given the level of the initial question I would say that keeping it siimple is the way to go. I would also argue that, given the context the correct answer is not to modify/create anything new it would instead be to *stream* the resulting changes to a TextWriter which would be both clean, simple and be maximally efficient. If in memory was ten required wrapping the API in a StringWriter is trivial...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm missing something, but would the following work?

```
int pos = 29;
if (myString[pos] != ' ')
    myString = myString.Insert(pos++, "-");
myString = myString.Insert(pos, "<br>");
```

Comment: Insert doesn't change the string (as it is immutable), instead, it's returning reference to new string, with inserted stuff, so you should probably using it like this: myString = myString.Insert(pos++, "-"); (the same applies to latter insert).

Answer (score 0):

was this supposed to be in c#?

```
String stuff = "blah...";
if ( stuff.Length > 30 )
{
  stuff = stuff.Substring(0,30) + "<BR>" + stuff.Substring(30);
}
```

Comment: Wow, this results in 5 new strings in memory... What's wrong with using Insert()?

Comment: Insert won't get rid of the space if at position 30.

Comment: Only in XHTML is <br> <br />, as seen here: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_br.asp

Comment: @James - I am not sure the code above gets rid of space at position 30 either. Also, I didn't see any requirements to get rid of a space, only to add a hyphen if there is a space, which the above code clearly does not meet, as homestead commented.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use Trim() after the first substring, to get rid of the space at the end, then you can add the 
 and I would do a Trim() on the second substring in case there was a leading space, as that would look funny.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
static void Main()
{
    string x = "abcdef";

    if (x.Length > 3)
    {
        if (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(x[3]))
            x = x.Insert(3, "-<br />");
        else
            x = x.Insert(3, "<br />");
    }

    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

You should of course change indexes (3 in this case) to 29.
Also, I've changed your space requirement to WhiteSpace, to cover more scenarios like new line etc. As Franci has stated in comment, you probably should check for more special characters than that (maybe check if last character was `.IsLetterOrDigit()` ?)